# Docker: Error: Cannot find module /app/src/myapp.js

Tags: node.js, docker

When I build my container it seems to compile without any issues using:

```
docker build -t mycompany:1.0.0 .
```

When I check `docker images` the container displays.

When I try to host it locally using

```
docker run -p 8081:8081 -it mycompany:1.0.0
```

it returns an error saying:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/src/myapp.js
```

I feel like it shouldn't be this complicated. Here is my docker file:

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app/src
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD node myapp.js
EXPOSE 8081
```

What is off?

Comment: Your `WORKDIR` is `/app/src`, but you're `COPY`ing the file into `/app`.  If you `docker run --rm -it mycompany:1.0.0 bash` and poke around you can see how the filesystem layout doesn't match up.

Comment: What directory is `myapp.js` in?

Comment: the tree looks like this
app/src/myapp.js

@DavidMaze its def not copying correctly. I have to be more explicit in the COPY

Comment: Can you update your post with the tree-like directory of your application? I suspect that the Dockerfile is not in the right location!

Comment: You guys were right in that what I was copying was not the right path. I ended up doing `COPY . .` and that fixed most of the problems. Now there is a new error that will require me to tail the container.

Answer (score -1):

You can see from the error itself , you are not copying anything inside /app/src.
Your both COPY command's destination is /app. You need to place myapp.js inside /app/src.

Comment: the `src` can be inside the current working directory and is copied over by the command `COPY . /app`. It is also fine when both `COPY`'s destination is `/app`.

Comment: Cant you find error Error: Cannot find module '/app/src/myapp.js.
This means myapp.js isn't inside /app/src , question here was not whether we can copy to same destination or not. I have answered to give solution not the generic docker commands.